# How to merge lists if first element is the same in both lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to join sublists if first element is shared.

## Input

```
in = {{2, "stuff 1"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {2, "stuff 3"}, {6, "stuff 4"}, {6, "stuff 5"}};
```

## Desired Output

```
out = {{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4", "stuff 5"}};
```

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates /@ Flatten /@ GatherBy[in, First]`?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Elegant and fast! I didn't realise we could use `Flatten` and `GatherBy` like that. Thanks!

Comment: what is the desired output for `in2 = {{2, "stuff 1"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {2, "stuff 3"}, {6, "stuff 4"}, {6, "stuff 4"}}` ?  Is it `{{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4", "stuff 4"}}` or `{{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4"}}`?

Comment: @kglr In my particular situation all the second entries are distinct. But I get your point. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes that second entries, i.e., strings are distinct.

```
DeleteDuplicates /@ Flatten /@ GatherBy[in, First]
```

> {{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4", "stuff 5"}}

Answer (score 2):

```
in = {{2, "stuff 1"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {2, "stuff 3"}, {6, "stuff 4"}, {6, "stuff 5"}};


KeyValueMap[Flatten @* List] @ GroupBy[First -> Last] @ in
```

> ```
> {{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4", "stuff 5"}}
> ```

```
in2 = {{2, "stuff 1"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {2, "stuff 3"}, {6, "stuff 4"}, {6, "stuff 4"}};

KeyValueMap[Flatten @* List] @ GroupBy[ First -> Last] @ in2
```

> ```
> {{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4", "stuff 4"}}
> ```

You can also use:

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ GroupBy[in, First -> Last, Sequence @@ # &]
```

> ```
> {{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4", "stuff 5"}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, "stuff 1"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {2, "stuff 3"}, {6, "stuff 4"}, {6, "stuff 5"}};
```

Using `Merge` and `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
KeyValueMap[Flatten @* List] @ Merge[#&] @ MapApply[Rule, list]
```

{{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4", "stuff 5"}}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `GatherBy`:**

```
in = {{2, "stuff 1"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {2, "stuff 3"}, {6, 
    "stuff 4"}, {6, "stuff 5"}};
GatherBy[in, First] // Map[Flatten@{First@First@#, #[[All, 2]]} &]
```

---

> {{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4", "stuff 5"}}

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
in = {{2, "stuff 1"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {2, "stuff 3"}, {6, 
"stuff 4"}, {6, "stuff 5"}};
```

Then:

```
(Flatten@*List) @@@ 
 Normal@Merge[Association /@ (Rule @@@ in), Identity]
```

yields: {{2, "stuff 1", "stuff 3"}, {3, "stuff 2"}, {6, "stuff 4", "stuff 5"}}